# Testing toUpperCase with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm trying to test if the `String.toUpperCase` method is called with Jasmine. However whenever I try it just returns

> toUpperCase() method does not exist

Here is my Jasmine test:

```
spyOn(String,"toUpperCase")
$(@makeup.el).trigger(@e)
expect(String.toUpperCase).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Any ideas on how to test if that is called? It appears that `String` is a private class to the `window` object, and so I may not actually be able to test this. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `String.toUpperCase` function. There is, however, a `String.prototype.toUpperCase` function which is what `"pancakes".toUpperCase()` will use. You should have better luck with:

```
spyOn(String.prototype, 'toUpperCase')
#...
expect(String.prototype.toUpperCase).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

However, native functions aren't guaranteed to behave like functions that are implemented in JavaScript so don't be surprised if this doesn't work either.

Checking that the `toUpperCase` method has been called anywhere (which is what wrapping `String.prototype.toUpperCase` with a spy will do) seems a bit pointless since strings are used all over the place; spying on a particular string would make more sense but even then, this particular test still seems a bit pointless.

Comment: I'm testing the behavior of a function, and it's end result is to call that. So it's the best way to make sure everything is passing. Anyhow, you were right on how to test it. Thank you.